# jQuery localScroll & scrollTo simply won't work

Tags: jquery, scroll

I've used both `scrollTo` and `localScroll` several times before but I simply can't figure out why this won't work?

http://jsfiddle.net/vP3Vk/

The important JS-bit is:

```
$('#primary-nav').localScroll({
    duration:   250, 
    hash:       true
});
```

Everything above that is just the plugins.

The HTML is just standard `<a href="#some-id">...</a>` and `<h2 id="some-id">...</h2>` but there's a bunch of text in there and WordPress' menu-div:itus.

If you comment the call to `localScroll` you'll notice that the page scrolls properly so there's no problem with IDs. Since it stops scrolling natively when I call `localScroll` I can assume it targets the correct element (`#primary-nav`). If I change it to `#primary-navs`, for example, it does nothing. Also the #hash changes when it's run outside of an iframe (like on JSFiddle).

So why doesn't it scroll? Do I need to specify what to scroll? (the docs say that the whole window is scrolled unless you specify otherwise - which is what I want so...)

Thanks

Edit: This happens in Chrome Version 25.0.1364.172 under Ubuntu and Windows. It works fine in Firefox (I just noticed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the version of `scrollTo` that I was using wasn't compatible with either my Chrome version or the `localScroll` plugin. I went down a version and now it works.